# How can I create a timeline in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access I have an MachinesList and ActionsList. A Machine can be set to Active and set to Inactive several times per year. Each change of status has its own ActionID and ActionDate.
In VBA I added some code to get the first and last date the Machine is Active. As this can happen more than once I now can create a list with start- and enddates each time the Machine is Active.
Two questions:
1) Can this be done with a query instead of VBA?
2) Is it possible to display these dates in some sort of timeline in Access?

This is what I have to create my list of dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Requests.RequestNumber, Requests.MachineID, Actions.Assignee, Actions.Action, Actions.TRDate FROM SelectedIDs LEFT JOIN (Requests LEFT JOIN Actions ON Requests.RequestNumber = Actions.RequestNumber) ON SelectedIDs.MachineID = Requests.MachineID ORDER BY Requests.MachineID, Actions.TRDate;
```

I do need the RequestNumber and the Assignee (in case of Activation) for further use. And since the RequestNumber for Activation and Deactivation differ I cannot use the MIN(date) and MAX(date) functionality because of the GROUP BY clause.
The list produced in VBA looks somewhat like this:

```
2325          ID1234     29-11-2016    16-3-2017 
2323          ID1234     28-3-2017     27-4-2017 
2203          ID9999     25-1-2017     27-2-2017
```

This list I want to see in some sort of timeline in Access.
Something like this:
ID | wk01 | wk02 | wk03 | etc
88 | N | N | Y | Y | Y | N
99 | N | Y | Y | N  | N | Y

But any timeline is fine. Suggestions anyone?
Thanks, Karin

Comment: "Some sort of timeline" really much to work with, Karin. You are the designer.

Comment: I want to display the weeks of the year. Mark the weeks red if a Machine is Active. One line for each Machine that is active. Updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do, yes. Your resulting recordset will not be tabular, it will be more like { Week, MachineID, Active } and it will be up to you to format it for reporting purposes. It may take a few subqueries, for example an obvious one is max of activation date before the week's end, and min de-activation date after that activation date. If that deactivation date is before the week's start the machine was not active. The actual SQL depends on how your Week table is defined. If you don't have a week table things get a bit more complicated as you also need a sub-query that replaces the week table.

Comment: Thank you. I do not have a week table but can create a temporary one if needed.  Before Access we had an overview in Excel which was an easy overview for everyone. It will probably not be difficult to create an Excel export but that is not what I want. I'd like the overview to be displayed in Access.

Comment: You will definitely need some kind of table with the weeks, if you want to do this with SQL and not VBA. Then by JOINING it with a table that has your MachineIDs you have a table that has all the Week/MachineID combinations. From that point on JOIN subqueries as I described above to get the Active/No Active status.

Comment: If you can be sure that no week will go by without at least one machine being activated or deactivated, you can create your Weeks query from your requests table.